# Ionic/Firebase Success function after Auth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have this login function, which is working. But I'm trying to redirect only if no errors are catched. I tried this code below, but this doesn't work the way I want, any ideas, like a success function that I don't know ?

```js
$scope.loginEmail = function($email, $password){
 
var testing = 1;
$scope.error = '';

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword($email, $password).catch(function(error) {

  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  $scope.error = errorMessage;
  testing = 0;
  console.log("Testing 1 : ", testing);
  
});

if(testing === 1)
{
    console.log("Testing 2 : ", testing);
    $state.go("menu.VNements");
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The function returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) - the `catch` is for errors and the `then` is for success.

```
function signInSuccess(response) {
  console.log('signInSuccess', response);
}

function signInError(response) {
  console.log('signInError', response);
}

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword($email, $password)
  .then(signInSuccess);
  .catch(signInError);
```

Comment: This will indeed work. The reason the Firebase documentation doesn't highlight this approach, is that when a user revisits the same page you typically don't want them to have to sign in again. By [listening for `onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) (instead of `then()` of the sign-in method), you can pick up the existing auth state.

Comment: I'm curious, how would you use the existing auth state ? Could you show me an exemple ?

Answer (score 1):

For more clarity I put my code here, it works, thanks to Dominic Tobias !

```js
$scope.loginEmail = function($email, $password){
 
    function signInSuccess(response) {
        console.log('signInSuccess : ', response);
        $state.go("menu.VNements");
    }

    function signInError(response) {
        console.log('signInError : ', response);
    }

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword($email, $password)
  .then(signInSuccess)
  .catch(signInError);
```